# Incremental solving of GEKKO dynamic models

Tags: python, gekko

I would like to use GEKKO to incrementally solve a dynamic model. I need to insert some parameters at different points in the simulation that are determined stochastically using an external model.

As a simple proof of concept, I tried adjusting the PID control example from the [tutorial website](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/GekkoPythonOptimization) to solve in 10 minute increments.

```
m = GEKKO()

tf = 40
timesteps = np.linspace(0,tf,2*tf+1)
step = np.zeros(2*tf+1)
step[3:40] = 2.0
step[40:]  = 5.0

# Controller model
Kc = 15.0                    # controller gain
tauI = 2.0                  # controller reset time
tauD = 1.0                  # derivative constant
OP_0 = m.Const(value=0.0)   # OP bias
OP = m.Var(value=0.0)       # controller output
PV = m.Var(value=0.0)       # process variable
SP = m.Param(value=step)    # set point
Intgl = m.Var(value=0.0)    # integral of the error
err = m.Intermediate(SP-PV) # set point error
m.Equation(Intgl.dt()==err) # integral of the error
m.Equation(OP == OP_0 + Kc*err + (Kc/tauI)*Intgl - PV.dt())

# Process model
Kp = 0.5                    # process gain
tauP = 10.0                 # process time constant
m.Equation(tauP*PV.dt() + PV == Kp*OP)

setpoint_final = []
pv_final = []
output_final = []
for i in range(8):
    SP.value = step[10*i:10*(i+1)]
    m.time = timesteps[10*i:10*(i+1)]
    m.options.IMODE=7
    m.solve(disp=False)
    setpoint_final.append(SP.value)
    pv_final.append(PV.value)
    output_final.append(OP.value)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(timesteps[:-1],np.concatenate(output_final),'b:',label='OP')
plt.ylabel('Output')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(timesteps[:-1],np.concatenate(setpoint_final),'k-',label='SP')
plt.plot(timesteps[:-1],np.concatenate(pv_final),'r--',label='PV')
plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')
plt.ylabel('Process')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I should get something like this:

[image: plot of correct setpoint tracking]

Instead it seems to reset at each interval:

[image: plot of variables resetting at each interval]

Is there something I am missing or is this type of simulation not possible in GEKKO?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `m.options.TIME_SHIFT=10`, `m.options.IMODE=4`, and change the way the values are stored.

[image: PID Simulation]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

tf = 40
timesteps = np.linspace(0,tf,2*tf+1)
step = np.zeros(2*tf+1)
step[3:40] = 2.0
step[40:]  = 5.0

# Controller model
Kc = 15.0                    # controller gain
tauI = 2.0                  # controller reset time
tauD = 1.0                  # derivative constant
OP_0 = m.Const(value=0.0)   # OP bias
OP = m.Var(value=0.0)       # controller output
PV = m.Var(value=0.0)       # process variable
SP = m.Param(value=step)    # set point
Intgl = m.Var(value=0.0)    # integral of the error
err = m.Intermediate(SP-PV) # set point error
m.Equation(Intgl.dt()==err) # integral of the error
m.Equation(OP == OP_0 + Kc*err + (Kc/tauI)*Intgl - PV.dt())

# Process model
Kp = 0.5                    # process gain
tauP = 10.0                 # process time constant
m.Equation(tauP*PV.dt() + PV == Kp*OP)

setpoint_final = []
pv_final = []
output_final = []
m.options.TIME_SHIFT=10
m.time = timesteps[0:10]
for i in range(8):
    SP.value = step[10*i:10*(i+1)]
    m.options.IMODE=4
    m.solve(disp=False)
    setpoint_final = np.concatenate((setpoint_final,SP.value))
    pv_final = np.concatenate((pv_final,PV.value))
    output_final = np.concatenate((output_final,OP.value))

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(timesteps[:-1],output_final,'b:',label='OP')
plt.ylabel('Output')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(timesteps[:-1],setpoint_final,'k-',label='SP')
plt.plot(timesteps[:-1],pv_final,'r--',label='PV')
plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')
plt.ylabel('Process')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```